# Laravel Excel Import Currency Symbol

Tags: laravel-excel

I have a .ods file that has a price column.
When using Laravel Import, I got only price value but not currency symbol.
File Excel looks like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ba9e.png
Is there any way that I can get all value and currency symbols?

Comment: It may not be an option, but importing as a CSV will maintain the currency symbol within the cell.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using files from another website that can only export to .ods file. In the old project, I'm using SpreadsheetReader which can get symbols normally but I want to change to Laravel Excel which I think is more convenient in most cases.